# Matlab refuses to recognize dynare 4.5.7

Tags: matlab

I can install dynare, but Matlab refuses to recognize it.

I have installed dynare 4.5.7 and followed both the interface "Set Path"--> Add folder --> C:\dynare \4.5.7\matlab option (and not the "with subfolders" option).  I have also tried the command addpath C:\dynare \4.5.7\matlab in the command window. I'm following all the documentation/online forum instructions to a T.

However, Matlab only can find "dare" when I type in "dynare" or "help dynare".  I've tried unstalling and reinstalling several times.  I'm at my wits end--any suggestions?  I'm working on a brand new Windows 10 machine.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Ten seconds after I posted this (and after a week of struggling), I found the solution:  try addpath C:\dynare\4.5.7\matlab\4.5.7\matlab.  I don't know how the path got so messed up, but I just wanted to post this in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, I would recommend to use the dedicated Dynare forum at https://forum.dynare.org/

Comment: Please understand, this is not an answer to the question and perhaps not too welcome. To leave an annotation to a question, Stack Exchange offers the mechanism of comments. You might want to consider to use this mechanism instead.

Comment: I would have done so if possible. Unfortunately, comments require at least 50 reputation. And the reason for leaving that comment here is that occasionally post Dynare questions here at StackOverflow and do not get any answers, because the Dynare community is at a different place.

Comment: jpfeifer: guessed that. This 50 reputation thing to comment is a well-known obstacle. And I guess nobody will vote you down for that.